# SilverStripe theme doesn't recognise home page theme

Tags: php, html, css, themes, silverstripe

I have just restored a SilverStripe website which involved updating silverStripe from version 2.4 to the current version (3.1.9). I copied all the content, backed up the database and saved the template before deleting and reinstalling the site.

The website is using a custom theme which I have been able to copy back into the /Themes folder and then pick the correct theme in the settings.

I have two problems now and as I haven't changed anything I am not sure why its not working

**First: SilverStripe isn't recognising the Home Page template**
SilverStripe is just reading the general Page template

HomePage.ss

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <% base_tag %>
    $MetaTags(false)
    <title>$Title - Furturo - Design. Build. Outdoor</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="themes/forturo/javascript/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="themes/forturo/javascript/jquery.innerfade.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="themes/forturo/javascript/forturo.js"></script>

    <script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-56783648-1', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');

    </script>

    <% require themedCSS('reset') %>
    <% require themedCSS('reset-font-grids') %>
    <% require themedCSS('sifr') %>
    <% require themedCSS('forturo') %>
    <title>Forturo</title> 
    </head>
    <body id="home">
    <div id="custom-doc" class="yui-t7">
    <div id="bg">

    <div id="hd">
    <img src="themes/forturo/images/design-top-left.gif" alt="" id="top-left">
    <h1>Forturo - Design. Build. Outdoor - Architectural Design. Draughting. Building Services</h1>
    <% include HomeNav %>
    </div>
    <div id="bd">
    <div class="yui-gd">
    <div id="pngwrap">
    <img src="themes/forturo/images/home/home-blue-stripe.png" alt="" width="123" height="631" id="blue">
    <img src="themes/forturo/images/home/home-green-stripe.png" alt="" width="123" height="631" id="green">
    <img src="themes/forturo/images/home/home-orange-stripe.png" alt="" width="123" height="631" id="orange">
    </div>
    <div class="yui-u first nav">
    </div>
    <div class="yui-u second">
    <div id="rotatingImageHolder">
    <ul id="mainImage">
          <% if HomePageImage1 %><li><img src="$HomePageImage1.URL" alt="" class="image3"></li><% end_if %>
          <% if HomePageImage2 %><li><img src="$HomePageImage2.URL" alt="" class="image2"></li><% end_if %>
          <% if HomePageImage3 %><li><img src="$HomePageImage3.URL" alt=""  class="image1"></li><% end_if %>
          <% if HomePageImage4 %><li><img src="$HomePageImage4.URL" alt=""  class="image4"></li><% end_if %>
          <% if HomePageImage5 %><li><img src="$HomePageImage5.URL" alt=""  class="image4"></li><% end_if %>
          <% if HomePageImage6 %><li><img src="$HomePageImage6.URL" alt=""  class="image4"></li><% end_if %>
    </ul>

    </div>

    <div>
    <a href="Design" class="design-button button">Design</a>
    <a href="Outdoor" class="outdoor-button button">Green</a>
    <a href="Build" class="build-button button">Build</a>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    </div>
    <div id="ft">
    <div id="textholder"></div>
    </div>
    </div><!-- /#bg -->
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Page.ss

```
   <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <% base_tag %>
    $MetaTags(false)
    <title>$Title - Forturo - Design. Build. Outdoor</title>
    <% require themedCSS('reset') %>
    <% require themedCSS('reset-font-grids') %>
    <% require themedCSS('sifr') %>
    <% require themedCSS('forturo') %>

    <!-- sifr scripts -->
    <script src="/themes/forturo/javascript/sifr.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // from sifr 3 site:
    var hneue = {
    src: 'themes/forturo/fonts/helvetica_neue.swf'
    ,css: {'.sIFR-root': { 'text-align': 'left', 'font-weight': 'normal', <% if menuImage = "build" %>'color': '#F77419',<% else_if menuImage = "green" %>'color': '#8fe000',<% else_if menuImage = "design" %>'color': '#0193E8',<% else %>'color': '#BEAD75', <% end_if %> 'font-size': '57px', 'z-index': '0'}}
    ,ratios: [7, 1.32, 11, 1.31, 13, 1.24, 14, 1.25, 19, 1.23, 27, 1.2, 34, 1.19, 42, 1.18, 47, 1.17, 48, 1.18, 69, 1.17, 74, 1.16, 75, 1.17, 1.16],

    <% if isGalleryPage %>
    // stop flash floating over lightbox
    wmode: 'transparent'
    <% end_if %>
    };
    //sIFR.domains = ['novemberborn.net'];
    sIFR.useStyleCheck = true;
    sIFR.activate(hneue);

    sIFR.replace(hneue, {
    selector: 'h2'
    });

    </script>

    <script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-56783648-1', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');

    </script>
    </head>
    <body
    <% if menuImage %>
    id="{$menuImage}"
    <% end_if %>
    class="$ClassName">
    <div id="custom-doc" class="yui-t7">
    <div id="bg">
    <div id="hd">
    <% if menuImage %>
    <img src="/themes/forturo/images/{$menuImage}-top-left.gif" alt="" id="top-left">
    <% end_if %>
    <% include AuxNavigation %>
    <% include CategoryNav %>

    </div>
    <div id="bd">
    <div class="yui-gd">
    $Layout
    </div>

    </div>
    <div id="ft"></div>
    </div><!-- /#bg -->
    </div>

    <div class="yui-t7" style="width: 76.92em; padding-bottom: 20px;">
    All content, images and designs are copyright Forturo, 2015
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

HomePage.php

```
    <?php

    class HomePage extends SiteTree {

    public static $db = array(
    );

    static $has_one = array(
    'HomePageImage1' => 'Image',
    'HomePageImage2' => 'Image',
    'HomePageImage3' => 'Image',
    'HomePageImage4' => 'Image',
    'HomePageImage5' => 'Image',
    'HomePageImage6' => 'Image',
    );

    function getCMSFields() {
    $fields = parent::getCMSFields();
    // add image fields
    $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Content.Main", new ImageField('HomePageImage1', 'Image'));
    $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Content.Main", new ImageField('HomePageImage2', 'Image'));
    $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Content.Main", new ImageField('HomePageImage3', 'Image'));
    $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Content.Main", new ImageField('HomePageImage4', 'Image'));
    $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Content.Main", new ImageField('HomePageImage5', 'Image'));
    $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Content.Main", new ImageField('HomePageImage6', 'Image'));
    // remove content field (unused)
    $fields->removeFieldFromTab("Root.Content.Main", 'Content');
    return $fields;
    }

    }

    class HomePage_Controller extends ContentController {

    public function init() {
    parent::init();

    // Note: you should use SS template require tags inside your templates
    // instead of putting Requirements calls here.  However these are
    // included so that our older themes still work
    Requirements::themedCSS("reset-fonts-grids"); 
    Requirements::themedCSS("forturo");  
    }

    /**
    * Site search form 

    function SearchForm() {
    $searchText = isset($_REQUEST['Search']) ? $_REQUEST['Search'] : 'Search';
    $fields = new FieldSet(
    new TextField("Search", "", $searchText)
    );
    $actions = new FieldSet(
    new FormAction('results', 'Search')
    );

    return new SearchForm($this, "SearchForm", $fields, $actions);
    }
    */

    /**
    * Process and render search results

    function results($data, $form){
    $data = array(
    'Results' => $form->getResults(),
    'Query' => $form->getSearchQuery(),
    'Title' => 'Search Results'
    );

    return $this->customise($data)->renderWith(array('Page_results', 'Page'));
    }
    */

    function extension(){
    return Page_Controller::extension();
    }
    }

    ?>
```

Page.php

```
    <?php

    class Page extends SiteTree {

    public static $db = array(
    );

    public static $has_one = array(
    'ContentImage' => 'Image'
    );

    public function getCMSFields(){
    $fields = parent::getCMSFields();
    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Content.Images', new ImageField('ContentImage', 'Content Image (appears at the top of the content)'));
    return $fields;
    }

    // menu function - is this a design page?
    function isDesign(){
    return Page_Controller::testSectionType('design');
    }

    // menu function - is this a build page?
    function isBuild(){
    return Page_Controller::testSectionType('build');
    }

    // menu function - is this an outdoor page?
    function isOutdoor(){
    return Page_Controller::testSectionType('green');
    }

    // stop aux menu items showing in main menu
    function isAuxiliary(){
    return Page_Controller::testSectionType('Auxiliary');
    }

    }

    class Page_Controller extends ContentController {

    public function init() {
    parent::init();

    // Note: you should use SS template require tags inside your templates
    // instead of putting Requirements calls here.  However these are
    // included so that our older themes still work
    Requirements::themedCSS("reset-fonts-grids"); 
    Requirements::themedCSS("forturo");     
    }


    // test which section this page lives in
    function testSectionType($sectionName){

    $sectionName = strtolower($sectionName);

    if (strtolower($this->Title) == $sectionName){
    return true;
    }

    else if(is_object($this->Parent) and isset($this->Parent->Title) and strtolower($this->Parent->Title) == $sectionName){ 
    return true;
    }
    else if (is_object($this->Parent->Parent) and isset($this->Parent->Parent->Title) and strtolower($this->Parent->Parent->Title) == $sectionName ){
    return true;
    }
    else if(is_object($this->Parent->Parent->Parent) and isset($this->Parent->Parent->Parent->Title) and strtolower($this->Parent->Parent->Parent->Title) == $sectionName){
    return true;
    }

    else{
    return false;
    }
    }

    // set menu top image ("design", "outdoor" etc)
    function menuImage(){
    $imgName = '';
    if($this->testSectionType('Design')){
    return 'design';
    }
    else if($this->testSectionType('Build')){   
    return 'build';
    }
    else if($this->testSectionType('green')){
    return 'green';
    }
    else{
    return false;
    }

    }


    function currentPage(){
    if($this->Parent->Title){
    return $this->Parent->Title;
    }
    else{
    return false;
    }
    }

    }

    ?>
```

PageComponant.php

```
    <?php
    // 'components' which are assembled into page sections at runtime
    class PageComponent extends SiteTree {

    public static $db = array(
    );

    public static $has_one = array(
    );

    // used by nav and content to see if we're processing a component (treated differently)
    function isComponent(){
    return true;
    }   
    }

    ?>
```

**Second: The theme isn't displaying correctly.**

The home page(index) should look like this
https://web.archive.org/web/20140516185945/http://forturo.co.nz/
Except the photos are a slideshow

The rest of the Pages should look like
https://web.archive.org/web/20140529044618/http://forturo.co.nz/photo-gallery/

css

```
    /* --------------------------
    Home:
    - arrows above base category links
    - colour panels in bg image
    -

    Interior
    - spash pages for sections
    - content images for int pages
    - subsection internal links for pages
    - sections for gallery page
    - design / green / build in templates
    - non category pages for aux links
    - rework contact page
    - browser testing
    ----------------------------- */

    html{
    background-color: #eee;
    }
    div#custom-doc{
    width:76.92em;
    *width:75.07em;
    min-width:1000px;
    margin:auto;
    text-align:left; 
    background: transparent url(../images/shadow.gif) bottom right repeat-y;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 20px 20px 0;
    }

    div#bg{
    background: #323232 url(../images/forturo-main-bg.gif) top left no-repeat;
    }

    #hd img#top-left{
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 0;
    }

    /**
    *
    * home page
    **/
    body#home div#bg{
    background-image: url(../images/home/home-bg.gif);
    padding-bottom: 163px;

    }

    body#home img#top-stripes {
    position: relative;
    top: 12px;
    }

    body#home .design-button:hover {
    color: #0089ee;
    }

    body#home .outdoor-button:hover{
    color: #7bdb00
    }
    body#home .build-button:hover{
    color: #ff6c00;
    }

    body#home #bd div.first div{
    padding-top: 105px;
    margin-left: 128px;
    }

    body#home .yui-gd .second{
    padding-top: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: -2px;
    left: 122px;
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 858px;
    }

    body#home .yui-gd .second img#mainimage{
    display: block;
    }

    body#home img#desc{
    display: block;

    }

    /* content pages - white bg */
    .second{
    padding-top: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    left: 2px;
    }


    .yui-gd .second .content{
    background-color: #fff;
    min-height: 546px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 11px 10px 10px 20px;
    }

    div#pngwrap {
    position: relative;
    left: 402px;
    top: -42px;
    width: 596px;
    height: 1px;
    overflow: visible;
    text-align: right;
    }

    ul#categorynavImage {
    position: relative;
    left: -2px;
    }

    img.hide {
    display: none;
    }

    body#home img#orange, body#home img#blue, body#home img#green{
    position: relative;
    overflow: visible;
    z-index: 10;
    left: 2px;
    }

    body#home img#green, body#home img#green-button{
    left: -125px;
    }


    body#home img#blue, body#home img#blue-button{
    position: relative;
    left: -249px;
    }


    .button {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    height: 55px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    margin-top: 84px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    position: relative;
    left: -5px;
    z-index: 11;
    }

    #textholder {
    width: 448px;
    height: 29px;
    position: relative;
    left: 141px;
    top: 10px;
    background-position: top left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }


    /* custom widths for body row */
    .yui-gd div.first{
    width: 39.75%;
    }

    .yui-gd .yui-u{
    width: 58.25%;
    }

    /*
    header
    */
    img#home-link{
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    top: -44px;
    left: 40px;
    }

    #hd img{
    display: block;
    margin-left: 619px;
    clear: left;

    }

    #hd ul li {
    display: inline;
    }

    #hd ul li a{
    color: #cccccc;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 10px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #808080;
    padding: 30px 15px 0 15px;
    }


    #hd ul#aux{
    margin: 0 0 30px 632px;
    text-align: right;
    }

    #home ul#aux {
    margin-bottom: 31px;
    }

    #hd #categorynav {
    margin-left: 127px; 
    }


    #hd ul#categorynav li{
    display: inline;
    }

    #hd ul#aux li a:hover{
    background: transparent url(../images/nocat-aux-hover-bg.gif) top center no-repeat;
    color: #fff;
    }

    body#design #hd ul#aux li a:hover, body#home #hd ul#aux li a.outdoor-button:hover{
    background-image: url(../images/build-aux-hover-bg.gif);
    }

    body#green #hd ul#aux li a:hover, body#home #hd ul#aux li a.outdoor-button:hover{
    background-image: url(../images/outdoor-aux-hover-bg.gif);
    }

    body#build #hd ul#aux li a:hover, body#home #hd ul#aux li a.build-button:hover{
    background-image: url(../images/aux-hover-bg.gif);
    }

    #hd ul#categorynav{
    margin-left: 145px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    }

    #hd ul#categorynav li{
    padding-right: 30px;
    }

    #hd ul#categorynav li a{
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #808080;
    }


    /* section and hover states */
    #hd ul#categorynav li a#hdr-design:hover, body#design #hd ul#categorynav li a#hdr-design{
    color: #0193e8;
    }

    body#build #hd ul#categorynav li a#hdr-build, #hd ul#categorynav li a#hdr-build:hover{
    color: #f77419;
    }

    body#green #hd ul#categorynav li a#hdr-outdoor, #hd ul#categorynav li a#hdr-outdoor:hover{
    color: #97ce00;
    }


    h1{
    text-indent: -9999px;
    height: 1px;
    }


    /* body row */
    .yui-gd{
    margin-top: 12px;
    }

    /**
    * nav
    **/ 
    #bd .yui-gd .nav div{
    margin-top: 37px;
    margin-left: 136px;
    }

    #bd .yui-gd .nav ul{
    min-height: 234px;
    margin-top: 12px;
    width: 278px;
    background: transparent url(../images/nav-bg.gif) top left no-repeat;
    padding-top: 4px;
    }

    #bd .yui-gd .nav ul li{
    background: transparent url(../images/nav-bg.gif) bottom left no-repeat;
    padding: 1px 0 6.75px 15px;
    }

    #bd .yui-gd .nav ul li a{
    color: #92928f;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 85%;
    }


    /* nested nav */
    #bd .yui-gd .nav ul li ul{
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: none;
    min-height: 10px;
    margin-top: 0;
    width: 272px;
    position: relative;
    left: -13px;        
    }

    #bd .yui-gd .nav ul li ul li{
    padding: 6.75px 0 1px 23px;
    background-position: top left;
    }

    #bd .yui-gd .nav ul li ul li a{
    background: transparent url(../images/nav-indicator.gif) 0 5px no-repeat;
    padding: 2px 2px 2px 10px;
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    }

    #bd .yui-gd .nav ul li ul li a:hover{
    background-image: url(../images/nav-indicator-active.gif);  
    }

    body#design #bd .yui-gd .nav ul li ul li a:hover{
    background-image: url(../images/nav-indicator-design-active.gif);   
    }


    /* link hover - sections */
    body#green #bd .yui-gd .nav ul li a:hover{
    color: #97ce00;
    }

    body#build #bd .yui-gd .nav ul li a:hover{
    color: #f77419;
    }

    body#design #bd .yui-gd .nav ul li a:hover{
    color: #0193e8;
    }


    #bd .yui-gd .nav img#latest-news {
    position: relative;
    left: 5px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    }


    #bd .yui-gd .nav img#phone-number {
    position: relative;
    left: -120px;
    top: -22px;
    }

    img#categoryimage {
    margin-top: -80px;
    position: relative;
    left: -119px;
    top: -29px;
    }


    /* ---------------------------
    content area
    ------------------------------ */
    .content h2{
    font-size: 47px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #f88635;
    margin-top: 19px;
    background: #fff url(../images/dots.gif) bottom right no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    left: 13px;
    margin-left: -13px;
    }

    .content strong {
    font-weight: bold;
    }

    .content h2 + img {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 10px;
    position: relative;
    left: 1px;
    }

    /* header colous for each section */
    body#build .content h2{ color: #0193e8;}

    body#green .content h2{
    color: #97ce00;
    }


    div.backtotop{
    margin-top: 20px;
    background: #fff url(../images/backtotop-bg.gif) center right no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    left: 14px;
    }

    div.backtotop a{
    color: #808080;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 90%;
    padding-left: 15px;
    background: #fff url(../images/backtotop-arrow.gif) center left no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    left: -14px;
    }

    div.backtotop a:hover{
    color: #3f3f3f;
    }

    /* general text styles */
    .content *{
    font-family: trebuchet, "trebuchet MS", helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #3b3b3b;
    }

    .content p{
    margin: 10px 0;
    }

    .content .text, .content textarea {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    }

    .content h4{
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    }


    /* ---------------------------
    gallery pages
    ------------------------------ */
    .gallery strong{
    font-weight: normal;
    }

    body#design .gallery strong {
    color: #0193e8;
    }

    body#build .gallery strong {
    color: #F77419;
    }

    body#green .gallery strong {
    color: #8fe000;
    }

    .gallery #ImageGallery table td {
    padding: 0 16px 16px 0;
    }

    /* ----------------------------
    blog
    ----------------------------- */
    h4 a{text-decoration: none}
    h4 a:hover{text-decoration: underline}
    span.authorDate{
    color: #FFBE8F;
    }


    p#copyright {
    width: 1000px;
    text-align: left;
    }


    /*
    * filters
    **/

    /* webkit */
    @media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0){
    /* shift content area right a touch */
    .yui-gd .second{
    position: relative;
    left: 2px;
    }

    /* shift home rollover images left 1px each*/

    }

    /* opera 9.5+ */
    @media all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:10000), not all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    /* home - rotating images and floating png's */
    :root body#home .yui-gd .second{
    left: 6px; top: 12px;
    }

    :root body#home img#top-stripes{
    top: 26px;
    }

    :root .yui-gd .second{
    position: relative;
    left: 11px;
    }

    }

    /* ie 7 */

    /* stop nav dropping down */
    * + html #bd .yui-gd .nav ul, * + html #bd .yui-gd .nav ul li ul{
    width: 262px;
    }

    * + html div.backtotop {
    left: 12px;
    }
```

Hopefully someone can help me out, thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

2.4 to 3.1 is a pretty big jump in terms of compatibility... did you read over the upgrading guides? Going over the 2.4 -> 3.0 guide first might be useful. http://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.0/changelogs/3.0.0/

Also unsure what this is doing...

```
function extension(){
    return Page_Controller::extension();
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what the functions are for. The theme was built by someone else years ago and the site has basically never been touched.

Comment: @Calvin You should know what the function is for if you plan to migrate it. Its never a good idea to chuck ALL of the codes as its hard to debug the issues. So do it bit by bit so just start from the bare minums on a empty ss installation. First copy the HomePage and the controller class wihtout any db additions and run dev/build?flush=all and make sure the HomePage.ss is picked up when you create a page on the cms with that type. Then just copy more of the codes segment by segment. Also read up on what cam suggested.

Comment: As a tip check that the HomePage.ss is written like that and not Homepage.ss. If you changed the servers filesystem might be handling uppercase chars right now and wont pick that up.

Comment: also I noticed that the $db, $has_one etc should be declared with `private static $db` etc.

Comment: if you are going to run SS3.1 then you'll want to update your statics to private (as these are immutable and handled via our config system).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem some time ago. It was solved by checking that the `_Controller` is named correctly (`PageType_Controller`, i.e. `HomePage_Controller`) and the template file has the equivalent name `HomePage.ss`. Make sure that the template files are in the correct path (e.g. `themes/themename/templates/HomePage.ss`).

Also you could possibly extend `Page` instead of `SiteTree` in `HomePage`. And the same for controllers. The `function extension()` can also be problematic.